# Angular UI Typeahead Limit Results when using Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I forked a Plunker as an example http://plnkr.co/edit/ylR1mel46FXTXzdvfHpa?p=preview

when using promises inline in the markup like so:

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <pre>Model: {{selected| json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in getStates($viewValue) | limitTo: 5">
</div>
```

if you type in "A" in the controller, you can see that the limitTo option is ignored.  Is this possible to use in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to limit the result in the callback of your promise.
**https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1740**

> AngularJS filters are executing synchronously and if you write your expression like address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue this part getLocation($viewValue) means that a filter would filter a promise object (which is noop as filter filter can only operate on arrays). The correct approach here is to do filtering on the server-side (this is the whole point of having async results from the server). If you still want to do further filtering on the client side you can do so in the promise callback function, in JavaScript.